Polarization Derivation
Can how I can find the phi and theta unit vectors as described (Eq. 4a and 4b) in the following paper on antenna cross polarization? I thought the thetha and phi unit vectors were the same as those of spherical coordinates, but that's not correct. Could someone explain how these unit vectors are determined? Here's the link to the paper: The Definition of Cross Polarization
The equation I'm referencing is:












Which refers to the second column of this diagram:













I'm confused by your question.  The paper explicitly shows the geometry they are using, including the definitions of the angles and unit vectors you're wondering about.  In addition, it explicitly mentions the use of spherical coordinates.

Please do not delete and repost closed questions. Original question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/817880/174766

@march Yes, I see the geometry and angles, but was unable to arrive at the derived unit vectors. I was asking for help on how the unit vectors for phi and theta were derived. (4a and 4b).

It seems like they are taking the spherical unit vectors,
$$\begin{pmatrix}i_x\\ i_y\\ i_z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}sin\left(\theta \right)cos\left(\phi \right)&cos\left(\theta \:\right)cos\left(\phi \:\right)&-sin\left(\phi \right)\\ sin\left(\theta \:\right)sin\left(\phi \:\right)&cos\left(\theta \:\right)sin\left(\phi \:\right)&cos\left(\phi \right)\\ cos\left(\theta \right)&-sin\left(\theta \right)&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\hat{r}\\ \hat{\theta} \\ \hat{\phi} \end{pmatrix}$$
and projecting the $\hat{i_\theta}$ and $\hat{i_\phi}$ onto a tangent plane to the position vector, $\hat{r}$, where the magnitudes of $\hat{i_\theta}$ and $\hat{i_\phi}$ are similarly, $\left\| \hat{i_\phi} \right\| =\left\| \hat{i_\theta} \right\| =\sqrt{1-sin^2\left(\theta \right)sin^2\left(\phi \right)}$. The paper is hard to read, but everything seems to be derived by gradient vectors per component in the form, $T\left(t\right)=\frac{r'\left(t\right)}{\left\| r'(t) \right\|}$
